# How to wait for server answer with asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript

For example I have Function like this :

```
function targetStarted() {

    setInterval(function () { // Content value
        gameResultCount.addEventListener = "";

    }, 1000);
```

how exactly asynchronous functions should be written instead of my sample.
this code sending request every second to the final website to get result.
final website can be like soccer result , live news about special character , live starting new game in special time ( when we want to start game before another players ) , live register before another people when we need to do it before another people , and any other samples

but this function has a problem:

it should send request to the website every second to Knowing when the target server responds
but this can cause too much pressure on the targeted website and server due to high demand

I want to get informed but i do not want to send request any time to the server
i think this problem can be resolved with asynchronous function
but how ? 
asynchronous function can be like under code

```
async function targetStarted()

let outresult = await...

setInterval(function () { // Content value
            gameResultCount.addEventListener = "";

        }, 1000);

}
```

i need a live sample to do this 
thanks ahead

Comment: What do you mean by live sample?

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with async functions. What you need is a way for the webserver to *push* updates to the client, instead of the client having to frequently *poll* the server. Look into websockets, SSE and/or long-polling.

Comment: @deceze why you kimited my account :|
You have reached your question limit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: @deceze i checked again with must of new explanations , i cannot send new questions , please resolve my account problem

Comment: @Barr J , my mean is another samples , explain about another programming with live sample about my problem in jsfiddle

Comment: @barr-j which people limited my question and my account ? :|

Answer (score 1):

> We want to get informed but do not send any second to the server i think this problem can be resolved with async func

No, asynchronous functions are used to remove the blocking in the requests, they have no concept of time — which is why they are based on the `Promise` objects in JavaScript. The time constraint is applied by *you*. They can take 1 second, 10 seconds or even 10ms to finish.

One suggestion: Do not use async/await on these complete HTTP requests. That is *definitely* going to slow down server and also would cause a huge load on the client's browser to send the requests and then load the response as well. I am assuming that you want to poll resources every second because you want to have a *real time* experience.

Instead, consider using **Socket.io** package and communicate using sockets. That is lightweight and fast in most cases, and communication on the direct sockets would be smoother as well. You can definitely implement asynchronous patterns in the socket communications, but **this will not have** a overhead of a complete HTTP request and response.

- You will be able to send the metrics **whenever available**.
- Clients **won't need to poll anything**, thus leaving most of the work on the server-side.
- Server-side would use event-driven approach to send the data down the clients, **as it is made available**.

This is what you should use for real-time apps in Node.js instead of sending HTTP requests every second.

For a tutorial and how-to, consider reading their official documentation, at https://socket.io/.

Secondly, since you mention *game*, here is a repository that you can use to get started with the Multiplayer game server developer with Socket.io and Node.js frameworks; https://github.com/benas/gamehub.io.